# How to change fucntion of a button when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey I am trying to build a website with a navigation bar that slides outn on the page which I have managed to do, but the button that opens the menu Isn't the same as the one who closes it. I want it to open and close it so I don't need to have more than one button. The example I followed to build it is from w3 schools: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp

I was thinking of using a else if statement but not sure how I would do that... 
everything short: I want to change the function openNav so has the same effect as openNav when the button hasn't been clicked and closeNav when is has been clicked. (Sorry if I'm not able to explain clearly enough) 
Thanks for all answers that will come:)

My code so far:

```
    /* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px and add a black background color to body */
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "150px";



}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0, and the background color of body to white */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";

}




<div id=main>
    <div id= button>
    <span onclick="openNav()"><div id=bar></div>
<div id=bar></div>
<div id=bar></div></span></div>
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to combine your two buttons and their functions into one, we get it:)

Comment: **Hint:** In the if-clause, check if `width == 0`. If so, then do code from `openNav()`, otherwise do code from `closeNav()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is make a different function that has a boolean in it to see if it is currently open or closed.

In that function, you can then open if closed, or closed if opened;

I have to warn you, didn't have much time so quickly typed this on my phone:

```
var open = false;

function decide(){
  if(open == true){
    closeNav();
  }else{
    openNav();
  }
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px and add a black background color to body */
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "150px";
open = true;


}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0, and the background color of body to white */
function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
open = false;

}
```

You'll only need one button if you use this. A button that triggers decide() which will then call one of the 2 functions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'd go with something like this i guess:

```
function toggleNav() {
    var d = document;
    var navWidth = d.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width;

    if (navWidth === "0" || navWidth === "") {
       d.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
       d.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "150px";
    } else {
       d.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
       d.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare a global variable and create a new function

example:

```
    var is_nav_open = false;

    function toggleNav() {
        if(is_nav_open == false) {
           is_nav_open = true;
            openNav();
        } else {
            is_nav_open = false;
            closeNav();
        }
    }
```

then change

```
    <span onclick="openNav()"><div id=bar></div>
```

and

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
```

to call our new function toggleNav()

like

```
    <span onclick="togglenNav()"><div id=bar></div>
```

and

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="togglenNav()">&times;</a>
```